# Player, Enemies and bullets Interaction ( Game Design )

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, cocos2d-x

I made a bullet hell game. Everything works as intended. Since I've never had any game design courses etc. I have concerns about the code ( quality wise and design wise).

What I do is store all the objects in GLOBAL VECTORS(i know its bad). such as

EnemiesArray

bulletsArray  //enemy bullets

playerBullets //player bullets

And for collision i have a Manager that checks collisions in update

```
for (auto playerBullet : playerBullets)
{
 for(auto enemy : EnemyArray)
    {


        if(enemy->checkCollision(playerBullet->bulletSprite->getPosition()) )
        {
           //collided
         }
    }
}
```

So when there is collision of bullets with enemies lots of things get effected. e.g. Background objects move, Player gets xp and Hud changes etc.

Manager contains the reference to bg hud and everything it needs.

Problem 1:

How do I get rid of global vectors. ( It allows me to create bullets/enemies from anywhere in the code).

Problem 2:
Should there be a manager to check bullet collisions? Or the object itself should check it? if so how do i give reference of enemies to the bullet.

Problem 3:
Manager is managing too many objects like I mentioned. (Sorry I sound stupid here). I hear one manager should be managing one kind of job.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to create my own game in the last few months. One of the major features was to let player shoot enemies. Your problems seem very similar to mine, so I will tell you how I dealt with them in my project.

Problem 1: My game consisted of a few levels. Every level was a separate object with their own containers for enemies / bonuses etc. The only place where it was possible to add creatures to the level was the constructor of the level. However, it would not be a problem to add them dynamically under certain circumstances. The point is that after completing specific level I got rid of all the objects that were assigned to it. The only thing that mainted were the information about the player and his score.

Problem 2: Every piece of dynamic events should have their own collision detector. The object itself should **not** be able to check it on their own. I would rather suggest creating another class like **Detector** and define a few methods that will deal with checking the collisions between players and enemies / player and bullets / bullets and enemies etc. (one method for one purpose). You might pass level's containers to the Detector so that it will be able to iterate through them and run the algorhytm that you define for a specific collision.

Problem 3: **Manager** should be an interface for every piece of your game design, for example for **BulletManager**, **EnemiesManager** - that's how I dealt with it.

I hope that you will find my solutions useful in any way.

Comment: For problem 1: lets say i create a object for level. then I have to add all objects for enemies. which is fine. But then when the enemy shoots. 
How will the bullets be added to the level? Do all enemies keep a ref of the level?

Comment: For problem 1: When the enemy shoots a new bullet has to be added to the vector of enemies' bullets. Those should be separated, I mean that player's bullets and enemie's should have their own containers, it's easier to iterate through when checking collisions. When the bullet that came from your enemy came into contact with the player the proper things should occur and as a result the bulet has to be deleted from the vector. In this way your gameplay consists of 3 phases, it means move of objects, shooting and checking collisions.